# LSB init service dependency

Tags: linux, bash, init

I have added the two services A and B. B is dependent on A, meaning that if I will start B then A should be start automatically if it is not running already. But A is not coming up automatically when I am starting B.

Can you please tell where I am wrong ? I have mentioned the Init scripts for both the services below.

I don't want to use upstart and systemd. I want to implement this using init scripts (LSB).

B Init script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author: xxxx xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx.xx

# chkconfig: 2345 95 05

# processname:  B
# config: /usr/local/etc/rc.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/B.pid


### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: B
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network A
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network A
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop System daemon
# Description:
### END INIT INFO
```

A Init Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author:       xxxx xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx.xx

# chkconfig:    2345 90 10

# processname:  A
# config: /usr/local/etc/rc.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/A.pid


### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: A
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop System daemon
# Description: 
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: I dont want to use upstart and systemd. I want to implement this using init scripts (LSB).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with LSB init scripts. They don't honor any dependencies itself.

That `INIT INFO` comment section is there only for dependency-based boot where the dependency is resolved by external scripts and used for starting individual init.d scripts during boot.

So in your current configuration the services A and B will be started in correct order during the boot, but manually starting one init script won't magically start the other (it even doesn't have any means of knowning if it is already running).

Some info on [dependency-based boot](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot) in Debian.